# Chrome And Chromium glitch horribly when running a wine program

Tags: wine, google-chrome

[image]the title says it all, when im using chrom and/or chromium, and i open a wine program this happens:

Comment: If you move the Chrome window around, does it recover?

Comment: nope, unforunatly